# How to get indexPath of new center UICollectionViewCell after one has been deleted?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal collectionView called postsCollectionView where each is as wide as the screen. Currently I am computing the indexPath of the currentPost with:

```
let currentPostIndex = Int(self.postsCollectionView.contentOffset.x / self.postsCollectionView.frame.size.width)
let currentPostIndexPath = IndexPath(row: currentPostIndex, section: 0)
```

When a post gets deleted and I have reset the "currentPost", I have this hacky method in my View Controller:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (postsFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count)! > 0 {
            print(postsCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems,postsCollectionView.contentOffset.x) //prints [],375.0
            //HACK
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { // change 2 to desired number of seconds
                let currentPostIndex = Int(self.postsCollectionView.contentOffset.x / self.postsCollectionView.frame.size.width)
                let currentPostIndexPath = IndexPath(row: currentPostIndex, section: 0)
                self.currentPost = self.postsFetchedResultsController.object(at: currentPostIndexPath)
            }
        } else {
            print("no items left")
        }
    }
```

Basically there is an NSFetchedResultsController that calls the collectionView's deleteItem method when the data source changes. I am using the callback didEndDisplaying cell in an attempt to - when the cell has been totally deleted, set self.currentPost to the now displayed post that has taken its place.

The problem is that this callback is called I think when the cell is deleted, but the animation hasn't finished so its still offset at 375 (the width of the screen) so it computes the current index path at 1 even though it should be 0 because now there is only 1 post in the collectionView.

Is there a way to wait until the animation is finished as well? Or is there a better way to compute the new indexPath of the collection view cell in the center after one has been deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Why don't you set currentPost to nil and recalculate it when you actually need it, instead of as soon as you have deleted the cell

2) You can use UICollectionView.indexPathForItem(at point: CGPoint) to get your IndexPath. It is probably a little safer. I guess the point you pass in would be

```
CGPoint(x:self.postsCollectionView.contentOffset.x, y:0)
```

The y position would be dependent on how you place you cell in the collection view.

If you need the result immediately. You know the current index before deletion. If the cell being deleted has index less than or equal to that then increment your current index, if the deleted cell's index is greater don't change it.

Comment: but I do need it right away. I need to update an additional view with notes so that the notes correspond to the now showing tag. How are you thinking I would calculate the point? If I just used the center point wouldn't that face the same problem of being called before the animation was completed?

Comment: And another comment about calculating current index right away